# SQL queries with NOT IN keyword

Tags: sql, vb6

```
select v.nroventa, sum(v.importe)
from ventas v, pagosventas p 
where v.nroventa=p.nroventa 
  and v.codigocliente=41 
  and v.nroventa not in (select p.nroventa 
                         from pagosventas p, ventas v 
                         where p.nroventa=v.nroventa)
group by v.nroventa
```

Why is this query wrong?

I'm getting syntax error right now, and VB doesn't highlight specific the part that's wrong when the error is thrown.

Comment: What is the error you got? Paste it please

Comment: It's just syntax error, it doesn't say where. I just assumed it was a missing word or something

Comment: Try it directly on the SQL engine you are using and show the error you got.

Comment: This query does not make sense (unless I am completely missing something). You're sub query on the `WHERE` clause is the SAME as the main query. So you are not going to get any results back! Someone correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I agree that that subquery appears to be a superset of the outer query, and so no results should ever be returned - perhaps if you gave some sample data and expected results, we might be able to construct a sensible query. Also, `JOIN` has been part of standard SQL for at least 20 years, and is implemented in every database system I can think of. Please start using it rather than `,` in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work. Try running it from sql server or any sql ide.

```
SELECT A.nroventa,A.sum_importe
FROM
(
select v.nroventa, sum(v.importe) AS sum_importe
from ventas v, pagosventas p 
where v.nroventa=p.nroventa 
  and v.codigocliente=41 
group by v.nroventa
) A,
(
SELECT v.nroventa
FROM ventas v
WHERE v.nroventa 
not in
(select p.nroventa from pagosventas p, ventas v where p.nroventa=v.nroventa)
) B
WHERE A.nroventa = B.nroventa;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an agg function on the first field of the select also, for example MAX(v.nroventa)

```
select MAX(v.nroventa), sum(v.importe)
from ventas v, pagosventas p 
where v.nroventa=p.nroventa 
and v.codigocliente=41 
and v.nroventa not in (select p.nroventa 
                     from pagosventas p, ventas v 
                     where p.nroventa=v.nroventa)
group by v.nroventa
```

Comment: What's in the `SELECT` list needs to *either* be in an aggregate function, *or* be part of the `GROUP BY` clause - `v.nroventa` is already satisfying that second requirement.

Comment: Nice spot @Damien_The_Unbeliever, perhaps it should return 0 records given the sub query, could the syntax error be related to the use of p and v again as aliases in the sub query, as well as in the main query?